# angular material dialog form save with $resource

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am trying to save form(angular material dialog) data, save(insert to DB table) and inject the saved data into parent element(background). This is my code:

```
//hospital.jsp
<img .... ng-click="showDialog($event)"  ....>

//hospitalService.js
app.factory('Hospital', ['$resource',
function($resource) {

    return $resource('http://localhost:8081/angular/rest/hospitals/:id', {/*id: '@id'*/}, {

        get: {method: 'GET', cache: false, isArray: false},
        save: {method: 'POST', cache: false, isArray: false},
        update: {method: 'PUT', cache: false, isArray: false}

    });

}]);

//hospitalController.js
app.controller('HospitalCtrl', ['$scope', 'Hospital', '$mdDialog', 
 function ($scope, Hospital,  $mdDialog) {

 $scope.hospitals = [];  

 var hospitals = Hospital.query(function() {
    console.log(hospitals);

  }); 
...
$scope.showDialog = function($event) {

             $mdDialog.show({
                 controller: DialogController,//HospitalCtrl,
                 controllerAs: 'hospCtrl',
                 targetEvent: $event,
                 clickOutsideToClose: true,
                 templateUrl: 'partials/modals/hospitalEdit.jsp',
                 parent: angular.element(document.body),
                 fullscreen: $scope.customFullscreen,
                 locals : {
                     hospitals : $scope.hospital
                 }

             }).then(function(answer) {
                 $scope.status = 'You said the information was "' + answer + '".';
             }, function() {
               $scope.status = 'You cancelled the dialog.';
             });

    };

    function DialogController($scope, $mdDialog, hospitals) {
    ...

        $scope.save = function(hospital) {

                $scope.save=function(){
                    $scope.hospital.$save(function(){
                        console.log("hospital saved");
                    });
                }
         };
//-------------------
hospitalEdit.jsp
 <form name="hospitalForm" ng-submit="hospitalForm.$valid && hospCtrl.save(hospital)" >
```

...
    ...
    Save

However, if I click the Save button, nothing happens and I get "$scope.hospital.$save is not a function" error when I click the Save button again.

thanks in advance,

Comment: You're mixing `controllerAs` with `$scope`. Pick one

Comment: You sending your hospital as an argument, but looking for it in scope. Also move `hospitalForm.$valid` to `ng-disabled="hospitalForm.$invalid"` for that button.

Answer (score 0):

I changed like this and it works.

```
 <form name="hospitalForm"  ng-submit="save(hospital)" >
...
<md-button type="submit" class="md-raised md-primary">Save</md-button>


function DialogController(
...
$scope.save = function(hospitalData) {

              $scope.hospital.$save(function(hospitalData){
                  hospital.push(hospitalData);
                });                         
                $mdDialog.hide();
         };
```

Thanks for your help.